# AsymptoticOutputTracker to Matlab-Simulink

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, implementation-details, control-systems

What is the structural scheme for `AsymptoticOutputTracker` in Mathematica? I need this in order to transfer the feedback signals received with the help of Mathematica to Simulink.

I found this picture in the book  Nonlinear Control Systems, Third Edition by Alberto Isidori.

[image]

But I'm not sure if this scheme is what I need.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for....do you have a SSM that you want tracked, or are you asking how Mathematica implemented the their output tracker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66636781/transfering-algorithms-asymptoticoutputtracking-to-matlab-simulink I assume this is also you?

Comment: @morbo

Yes, Cause I don't know which kind of specialists I need. According to Mathematica or Simulink.

Comment: @morbo It is better not to look for my topics on other thematic stacks, but help in resolving the issue.

Comment: @morbo, I mean how to build a diagram for asymptotic output tracking in Simulink?

Comment: it’s important to inform oneself. If people are going to help you, it’s helpful to know what has already been done. This is not a support forum for simulink, but mathematica and sometimes system modeler...ask at the matlab forums.

Comment: @morbo
I agree with you, but only partially. It is not always possible to provide best practices, especially when you do not know from which side to approach the problem. The only starting point at the moment is the diagram from the book, the page of which I have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this scheme is suitable. Then the results from Mathematica are reproduced in Simulink.

[image]

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect.html?q=SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect